# Meteor 1.3 split larger apps

Tags: meteor

We have a larger web service built with Meteor. As we are not happy with the generated app (it's more then 2MB of final JS) we would like to split the app into smaller sections, what in our case make sense.

Do you have any good strategy to organize code in such a case? 
Of course the easiest it to create separate git repos but then there is a shared code which is difficult to maintain.

I was considering if anyone knows some tricks to parametrize which  main.js should be used. For instance we would have:

```
server/main.section1.js
server/main.section2.js
server/main.section3.js
```

So in the end I would like to have something like:

```
meteor compile section1
meteor compile section2
meteor compile section3
```

As the result I would have three different apps but the code would be in one repo.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Single repo file structure:

```
section1
  -- Code specific to "section1" goes here
section2
  -- Code specific to "section2" goes here
section3
  -- Code specific to "section3" goes here
shared
  -- Shared files between "sections" goes here
```

### Long answer

Meteor at this time does not have a "multi-service" under one project functionality built into it right now (a la Django). But JS does support relative file paths for imports of other modules, so why not just split each service into its own Meteor project. Then at the root of the repo have a directory labeled `shared`. Now just simply import the shared codebase using relative file paths. See above for visual.